# Spring MVC - init binder on method return

Tags: validation, spring-mvc

I have a problem with `@InitBinder` and Spring validation.

Firstly, the code:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/manage")
public class QuestionManagementController {
...
    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        System.out.println("======"+binder.getObjectName());
        binder.setValidator(new QuestionListValidator());
        System.out.println("======"+binder.getObjectName());
    }
...
    @RequestMapping(value = "question/{unitid}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getQuestionEditor(@SessionAttribute("userEntity")
    UserEntity loggedUser, Model model, @PathVariable("unitid")
    long unitId) {
        QuestionUnit qu = questionUnitDao.getQuestionUnitById(
                QuestionUnit.class, unitId);
        QuestionList list = questionListDao.getParentQuestionList(qu);
        if (!isOwner(loggedUser, list)) {
            throw new Http404Exception("Nie znaleziono strony.");
        }
        else {
            model.addAttribute("questionUnit", qu);
            model.addAttribute("listid", list.getId());
            model.addAttribute("formUrl", "/manage/question/" + qu.getId());
            System.out.println("sdhfdsfihui");
            return "/question/adder/"
                    + questionAnnotationProcessor.getJSPName(qu.getClass());
        }

    }
```

now, using the power of println I have something like this when this method is invoked:

```
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - entering: initBinder
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - w/args:[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder@1dc696e]
======unitid
======unitid
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - entering:getQuestionEditor
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - w/args: [user, {}, 1245184]
sdhfdsfihui
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - entering: initBinder
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - w/args: [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExtendedServletRequestDataBinder@404629]
======questionUnit
class pl.meble.taboret.question.OpenQuestion
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - entering: handleMyException
INFO : pl.meble.taboret.controller.QuestionManagementController - w/args: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid target for Validator [pl.meble.taboret.validator.question.QuestionListValidator@1be6a65]: pl.meble.taboret.question.OpenQuestion@1f9cb2c]
```

so it looks that init binder is called before - which is normal and after method `return` statement. The string that is returned is the name of the Apache Tiles definition.

It is also strange, that init binder is invoked with `questionUnit`, validator is set, and then there is an error.

The list validator looks like this

```
@Component
public class QuestionListValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        System.out.println(clazz.toString());
        return QuestionList.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "name", "name.empty");
    }
}
```

and we can see the name of the class printed.

I don't know why this behaves like this, but I am pretty sure that this is the fault of `@InitBinder` without any parameter.

I read the spring documentation about this annotation `value` parameter, here it is

```
The names of command/form attributes and/or request parameters that this init-binder method is supposed to apply to.
Default is to apply to all command/form attributes and all request parameters processed by the annotated handler class. Specifying model attribute names or request parameter names here restricts the init-binder method to those specific attributes/parameters, with different init-binder methods typically applying to different groups of attributes or parameters.
```

So does it mean that without the parameter, validators validate everything that comes in (request parameters) and everything that goes out (command/form attributes)? If so, why there is no invocation of init binder with `userEntity` argument. And why `@InitBinder` is invoked after the controller method returns the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validators will not be called unless your parameter has a @Valid annotation, or if you call it explicitly. In your case they should not be getting called. However InitBinder methods will be invoked for every parameter like you are seeing.

At the point that the validator is set for a method parameter, the supports method of the validator is called to determine if the validator supports the parameter type, that is probably you are seeing the supports being called, however the validate method will not be called unless you have the @Validate annotation also

Comment: After reading your response and toying a bit with this annotation I now know how it works, thanks.